# Notation: Polynomial of the Differential Operator

Tags: notation, control-theory

I having difficulty with some notation relating to control theory. Given that $H(s)$ is a strictly proper, scalar transfer function (i.e. a ratio of polynomial functions with a higher degree in the denominator), the text I am following introduces:
\begin{equation}
H\left(\frac{d}{dt} \right) u(t) 
\end{equation} 
where $u(t)$ is the control function. Along with this, the text also gives the Fourier transform as:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F} \left( H \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right) u(t) \right) = H \left( i \omega \right) \hat{u}(i\omega) 
\end{equation} 
This seems to follow from $\mathcal{F} \left( \frac{d^n f}{dt^n} \right) = (i \omega)^{n} \hat{f}(i \omega)  $.If the polynomial was, for example, $p(s)= s^2 + 1 $, I would interpret $p\left(\frac{d}{dt} \right) u(t) $ as $\frac{d^2 u}{dt^2} + u $, but I am not sure if this correct, and it is not clear how to handle say $H(s) = \frac{1}{s^2 +s +1}$.

The text is: Athanasios C Antoulas. Approximation of large-scale dynamical systems, volume 6. Siam, 2005.

Comment: I would interpret this as follows: Suppose $H(s) = { n(s) \over d(s) }$ and $H({ d \over dt}) u(t) = y(t)$, then $n({ d \over dt}) u(t) = d({ d \over dt}) y(t)$. Frankly, I think the notation is gross.

Comment: Thanks, they do actually use that as well. But then they replace $\int u y dt$ with $\int u H \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right) u dt $. I just can't my head around what this actually means!

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses your issue, but just look at the $H()u$ notation as shorthand for the solution $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can think $s$ as a derivative operator in time domain, e.g. $(s^2 + s + 1)u(t) = \ddot{u}(t) + \dot{u}(t) + u(t)$. But it is not appropriate to use it like this because $s$ is a variable in frequency domain. I think that's why the authors chose the notation $\left( \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right)^2 + \frac{d}{dt} + 1 \right) u(t)$.